# validation not working on multiple select

Tags: codeigniter, formvalidation-plugin

here i have given validation for multiple select and even if i choose value from select field and gave submit then also its telling to select the field and am using codeigniter 3.0.6. searched alot but couldn't find the solution;
Here is my controller

```
function online_booking() {

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('course', 'Course', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch', 'Branch', 'required');

  if($crs = $this->input->post('course'))
  {
    $course = implode(',',$crs);
    var_dump($course); 
  }      

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
  {
    $this->load->model('branch_model');
    $data = array('course' => $course, 'branch' => $this->input->post('branch'));

    $id = $this->branch_model->insert_enquiry($data);
    if ($id) 
        {

      $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Booking has been Succeed,We will contact you shortly.');
      redirect('online-booking');
        } 
        else 
        {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Error has been occured,try again.');
      redirect('online-booking');
        }
  }
$data['active'] = 'online';
$data['program'] = $this->home_model->get_program();
$this->load->view('online_bookin', $data);
}
```

here is my view page

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Course to be opted*</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="course[]" id="course" multiple="multiple">
              <option value="">Select Course</option>
              <?php foreach ($program->result() as $row) if($row->parent_id !=0) {?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" <?php echo set_select('course',$row->id) ?> ><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
              <?php  } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
```

this is my callback function

```
function is_multiple_select() {
$crs=$this->input->post('course');
if(!$crs)
 {
   $this->form_validation->set_message('is_multiple_select','You did not select any course to upload.');
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
  return true;
 }
```

}

this is my model

```
public function insert_enquiry($data=array())
{
   if($this->db->insert(`enquiryform`,$data))
     {
       return $this->db->insert_id();
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
```

}

Comment: use a callback function and check the array count to echo the error.

Comment: i had used callback function at that time i got error like ` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`cours' at line 1`

Comment: MySQL error when callback? Post you call back function too... We can fix it

Comment: i had changed my code like this $this->form_validation->set_rules('course','course','callback_is_multiple_select');

Comment: is_multiple_select‌​() 's code plz

Comment: i had edited my question please see that

Comment: I changed the function try now...!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using this code:

```
if($crs = $this->input->post('course'))
  {
    $course = implode(',',$crs);
    var_dump($course); 
  }
```

Remove it and check if it works. Or place it inside the `$this->form_validation->run() == TRUE` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_multiple_select() {
   $crs=$this->input->post('course');
   if(!empty($crs) && count($crs)>0)
   {      
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('is_multiple_select','You did not select any course to upload.');
     return false;
   }    
}
```

//Changes

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
 {
//You can't save an array directly.
$data = array('course' => implode(",",$this->input->post('course') ), 'branch' => $this->input->post('branch') );
$this->db->insert(`enquiryform`,$data);
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

while retrieving explode the course it.

Comment: $data['program'] = $this->home_model->get_program(); is having SQL?
If its check that code... and post
echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: Post your model we can find it